# Sending an email from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a stored procedure to work in SQL Server 2005 that was written for SQL Server 2000.  It sends an email when called from an application.  I tried to run the first part of the stored procedure that creates an OLE object. The 2005 Server is 32-bit.  I get the error:

> OLE Automation error Information HRESULT: 0x80040154 Source:  ODSOLE
>   Extended Procedure Description:  Class not registered

This is the query that I am running:

```
DECLARE @object int
DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @property varchar(255)
DECLARE @return varchar(255)

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate '{DB486713-E4A9-11D3-AC19-00C04FA308B2}', @object OUT
IF @hr <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_displayoaerrorinfo @object, @hr
    RETURN
END
```

I don't know what kind of object that is created from the CLSID.  There is no documentation.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: If I recall, SQL 2000 didn't have [Database Mail](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(v=sql.105).aspx), like later versions of SQL Server.  To send mail in SQL 2000, you had to rely on external resources like MS Outlook or Extended MAPI.  That GUID (or maybe it's a class ID) passed to sp_OACreate might be for Outlook or MAPI.

Comment: Do you have a sample email?  Even without documentation, you might be able to reverse-engineer a quick solution with `Database Mail` and `sp_send_dbmail`.

Comment: Currently, the stored procedure works in SQL Server 2000.  I am trying to get the same stored procedure to work in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Yep.  Understood.  :)  How do you want to fix the problem?  I see two options:  1)  Make no changes to the stored proc and install/configure software on the SQL 2005 server host that corresponds to CLSID `{DB486713-E4A9-11D3-AC19-00C04FA308B2}`            2) Configure your SQL 2005 instance to use `Database Mail` and rewrite the stored proc to send email via `sp_send_dbmail`.  So....pick your poison.

Comment: I would like to start with option 1.  How do I find out what that software is with that CLSID?  Would I look at the registry of the server that is currently running it and find the name or is there a less dangerous way?

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of DBA-types that could help you with option #2.  For option #1, you don't really need SQL expertise.  That has more to do with COM (I think).  Developers might be better suited to help.  I guess you could start by searching for the CLSID in Regedit.

Comment: Thanks.  I will start there and see if I can get the email service to work without changing the stored procedure.